# Add datepicker to simple vuejs app

Tags: vue.js

I have this app running https://github.com/scotch-io/vue-todo

I have trying too add a datepicker field to each todo. I am using https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker.

I installed the datepicker with `npm install vuejs-datepicker --save` and in src/App.vue added:

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

Vue.component('my-component', {
    components: {
        Datepicker
    }
});
```

Now I am getting the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue

  ✘  https://google.com/#q=import%2Ffirst       Absolute imports should come before relative imports  
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:17:24
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
                          ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef      'Vue' is not defined                                  
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:19:1
  Vue.component('my-component', {
   ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent        Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4          
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:20:5
      components: {
       ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent        Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8          
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:21:9
          Datepicker
           ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle  Missing trailing comma                                
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:21:19
          Datepicker
                     ^

  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle  Missing trailing comma                                
  /Users/marklocklear/sandbox/vuejs/vue-todo/src/App.vue:22:6
      }
        ^


✘ 6 problems (6 errors, 0 warnings)


Errors:
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle
  2  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef
  1  https://google.com/#q=import%2Ffirst
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-24
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js
```

Comment: All of these errors seem very self-explanatory. What are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: This is an issue with also importing eslint I believe.  Do a web search for the error message `absolute imports should come before relative imports` and `eslint`  you may find something that will help you.   Also are you importing Vue before requiring the component.  That also may be the cause of the `Vue not defined` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in src/App.vue, you should add the import under the imports that already exist and then add Datepicker to the list of components.

```
<script>
import sweetalert from 'sweetalert';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import CreateTodo from './components/CreateTodo';    

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TodoList,
    CreateTodo,
    Datepicker
  },
. 
.
.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was close Tim, I just needed to move the import up. Here is what is working for me:

```
<script>
import sweetalert from 'sweetalert';
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import CreateTodo from './components/CreateTodo';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    TodoList,
    CreateTodo,
    Datepicker,
  },
```

Comment: Lumbee, I updated my answer.  Could you accept as correct answer?

Comment: Sure. Any suggestions on how to get the field to display correctly? I am trying this in CreateTodo.vue https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/d762bcf0e6c9129f78fe429b3222f1a8 and am just getting a regular text field, but no picker.

Comment: The picker looks like a regular field until you click on it.  Once you click on it, the picker will pop up.